# javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, jaxb

I am trying to fetch data using SOAP where I used SOAPEnvelope to bind the both header and body of the request. But while creating a new instance of

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SOAPEnvelope.class);
```

I am getting this Exception:-

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope
```

Please suggest solutions.

Thank You.

Comment: You should use a webservice client like Spring WebServices or Apache CXF for this.

Comment: Yes, I am using WebServices but am unable to resolve this issue. The main problem is with the SOAPEnvelope interface.

Comment: "SOAPEnvelope is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces." => Don't use interfaces, use classes!

Comment: You aren't as you are constructing the soap envelope yourself, the web service framework will do that for you. You only need to concern yourself with the body, not the soapy stuff that is the responsibility of the framework.